# want to move each array from arrayList into int [ ]

Tags: c#

there are 350 elements in my arraylist , each of it consist of an array of 9 integers i-e Count of each element is 9 . i want to retrievere each of it.
here is what i am trying but giving me 
**error**

> "Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]' to type
>   'System.Int32[]'."

```
FileName = "E:\\Normalized_sheet1.txt";
FileStream Fs = File.OpenRead(FileName);
StreamReader SR = new StreamReader(Fs);


while (!SR.EndOfStream)
{
    Line = SR.ReadLine().Split('\t');  //make an array of text each time
    List<string> arr = new List<string>();
    arr.AddRange(Line);
   List<int> intList = arr.ConvertAll(s => Int32.Parse(s));
    myvalues.Add(intList);

}

SR.Close();
Fs.Close();

for (i = 0; i < Samples; i++)
{
    InputParameter=(int[]) myvalues[i];     // Error
}
```

Comment: Can you point out the type of "myvalues"?

Comment: There is no need to use `ArrayList` now unless you are dealing with an API that requires it or an old version of .NET.  You can store a collection of arrays in a `List<int[]>` and get better type-safety. Or you can use `List<List<int>>` and avoid converting to an array.

Comment: I've added an answer but to be sure, we need to know : 1. type of myvalues, 2. type of InputParameter

Comment: myvaues and Inputparameter both have int types

Answer (score 0):

```
myvalues.Add(intList.ToArray());
```

Because you mentioned that you have a list *of arrays*. If it's a `List<int[]>` then you can't add lists to it - you can only add arrays. `ToArray()` returns an array of the items in your list.

Answer (score 0):

If "myvalues" is a List of int[] then your loop should look like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < Samples; i++)
{
    InputParameter= myvalues[i]; //don't need cast.  
}
```

if myvalues is a List of List of int, then your code should be:

```
for (i = 0; i < Samples; i++)
{
    InputParameter= myvalues[i].ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not cast, use the appropriate `List` method:

```
 InputParameter=myvalues[i].ToArray();
```